# Unable to access springboot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a SpringBoot app. When I start the application , I get a message saying *Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)*

However when I try to access the server by providing localhost:8080 in the browser I see - "This localhost page can’t be found"

**Main Class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.cloud.validator"})
public class Validator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Validator.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
public class TransactionController {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionComparator comparator;

    @RequestMapping(value ="transactions", method = RequestMethod.POST , produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<TransactionDetails> transactions(TransactionRequest request){
        return comparator.validateTransaction(request);
    }


}
```

**Application Properties**

```
server.contextPath=/txnscomparator
```

**Build.gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.3'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.8.1'
    compile(group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc6', version: '12.1.0.1')
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/txnscomparator?

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes , I saw the same error. But if I remove the server.contextPath , I see even localhost:8080 returning a response in the browser.

Comment: Have you tried localhost:8080/txnscomparator/transactions ?

Comment: yes , tried that as well.

Comment: try value ="/transactions"

Comment: Please check your spring boot application log if you find the below logs which mapped your application url path.

`INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/v2/schedules/{app_id}],methods=[PUT]}"`